# I am using CSS border property inside PHP but it's not working

Tags: php, css

I am using CSS border property inside php tag but it's not working. what should I do?

```
    <?php
    $table="<table cellspacing=40;style=border:2px solid black>";
    $table.="<thead>";
    $table.="<tr>";
    $table.="<th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>D.O.B</th> 
     <th>Password</th>";
    $table.="</tr>";
    $table.="</thead>";
    $table.="</table>";
    echo $table;
    ?>
```

According to me CSS property can use with PHP and execute also.

Comment: `$table='<table cellspacing="40" style="border:2px solid black">';` cellspacing is not a CSS and is seperated from the `style` attribute with a space not a `;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `;` semicolon to separate the attributes on table, you should separate them by spaces

just try like this

`$table='<table cellspacing="40" style="border:2px solid black">';`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the values of the attributes between ""

```
$table="<table cellspacing=\"40\" style=\"border:2px solid black\">";
```

Comment: They dont HAVE to be in any quotes actually. Quotes are required only if there is a space in the attribute value. And it can be a single quote or a double quote

Comment: If you don't use quotes the browser take  'solid' and 'black' as attributes not as part of style

Comment: NOTE that I mentioned ___Quotes are required only if there is a space in the attribute value___ and there is a space in the attribute value. I only mentioned this as your answer seemed to me to be saying YOU HAVE TO have quotes around attribute values, when in fact you only have to if there is a space in the value

Answer (score 0):

```
 $table="<table cellspacing=40; style='border:2px solid black'>";
```